# Connect Node JS with LDAP

Tags: javascript, node.js, ldap

How to connect to LDAP using node js? Kindly help with sample code.
I am not able to connect the LDAP as in post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134177/connect-ldap-using-node-js-segmentation-fault-error.

Comment: Closed as a dupe of a deleted question; voting to reopen.

Comment: @Ben I voted to leave closed, I don't think this question is clear enough and describing a problem that can be solved in a SO reasonable way.

Comment: @cheesemacfly: It can always be closed again with a different reason after it's been reopened. Since we have an option dedicated to unclear questions, I've gone ahead and substituted that now.

Comment: @BoltClock Got it. But what about the delete vote(s) already there? (I don't know if they were any, but just asking)

Comment: @cheesemacfly: When a question is reopened, any delete votes that were there will disappear.

Comment: @BoltClock So assuming (as an example) that this question had 3 delete votes. 5 more people with 10+K would have to go over it again to delete it? Is it worth reopen in this case? As this been discuss on meta before? (sorry if yes, I have never been in this situation before)

Comment: @cheesemacfly: If it didn't gather enough delete votes to be deleted before reopening then it's probably not that big of a deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer you [node-LDAP](https://github.com/jeremycx/node-LDAP).

In your application, you can use following structure

```
var ldap = require('LDAP');
var ldapObj = new ldap({ uri: 'ldap://your_server', version: 3});

//check your connection
ldapObj.open(function(err) {
    if (err) {
       throw new Error('Connection problem occured!');
    }
    console.log("Connected to ldap");

});

//Search
search_options = {
    base: '',
    scope: '',
    filter: '',
    attrs: ''
}

ldapObj.search(search_options, function(err, data){
   if (err) {
      throw new Error('Search filed');
   } else {
      console.log("Search result:" + JSON.stringify(data))
   }

});
```

For more detail on search_options you can refer [here](https://github.com/jeremycx/node-LDAP#ldapsearch)

Alternative option **node-ldapjs** is [here](https://github.com/mcavage/node-ldapjs)

Comment: This is not supported on Windows.